# How to design a latch from a truth table

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, latch

I am trying to design a latch using a truth table. The inputs to the latch are En and In. I think the circuit implementing the truth table should not change output when En is low, and output In when En is high. This is the truth table:

En | In | Prev | Out
0  | X  |   0  |  0
0  | X  |   1  |  1
1  | 0  |   X  |  0
1  | 1  |   X  |  1

It results in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg7fa7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I haven't seen this while looking around at latch schematics. Am I missing some concept here? Is this an incorrect latch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have seen similar latches and maybe this will help you to see how familiar this circuit is:

[image: rearranging the circuit]

Comment: Thanks, I think I was getting confused by the routing displayed in other schematics.